# How long till tomorrow (in hr::mi:ss)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want a mysql expression that will tell me how many hours:minutes:seconds till tomorrow.

If `now()` gives me: 2011-01-01 18:30:00; `date_add(date(now()), interval 1 day)` gives me "2011-01-02"

I am trying

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 DAY), NOW());
```

...but I am getting (NULL)

I should get (as per above example): 05:30:00

--- solved ---

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(CONCAT(DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 DAY), ' 00:00:00'), NOW());
```

--- revised question ---

Is there a way which could be more efficient?

Comment: If you solved it, post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the question, I have solved the problem:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(CONCAT(DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 DAY), ' 00:00:00'), NOW());
```

However, if there are more efficient ways of doing the same thing I would welcome responses.

Comment: I think there's no more efficient way. you should use `DATE_ADD` everytime.